# Why codeigniter shopping cart class doesn't allow any special character in the name?

Tags: php, frameworks, codeigniter

I have a question just like in the title - Why codeigniter shopping cart class doesn't allow any special character in the name? When I'm adding some item with normal name containing only standard characters it works like charm. However if I add something like, say, "word / word" or something like that it won't add anything to the shopping cart. Can someone provide me with some hints on that one please?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you look on **Cart.php** you will see on line 31 `var $product_name_rules    = '\.\:\-_ a-z0-9';`.

A nice way to change this variable is putting a MY_Cart.php on your application\libraries\MY_Cart.php with this code:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Cart extends CI_Cart {

    var $product_name_rules = '[:print:]';

}
```

Or you can also modify it when you add the product, using:

```
$this->cart->product_name_rules = '[:print:]';
$this->cart->insert(array());
```

Comment: Very useful tip. I think they should fix this.

Comment: Literally saved the day.

Comment: Not worked for me. I have changed  

$product_name_safe = FALSE; 

on system/libraries/Cart.php and fixed

Answer (score 11):

I just found this question from google while facing the same problem, but the answer ipalaus provided didn't fix my problem, because it still does not allow **greek** characters. After some more digging I found this :

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Cart extends CI_Cart {

    var $product_name_rules = '\d\D';

}
```

which basically **allows everything**. Enjoy!

Comment: Yes! this method worked for me with utf8 character set in product name.

Comment: worked for me too while the '[:print:]' did only on my local machine , your solution worked on the server too , thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can also optionally just modify the regular expression to allow quotes like so:

```
$this->cart->product_name_rules = "\.\:\-_\"\' a-z0-9";
```

Answer (score 0):

This all does not help on **UTF8 Characters** (etc **Serbian**), but i have made something like, before putting in chart use like this

```
$name=ucfirst(url_title(convert_accented_characters($name), ' ', TRUE));
```

And modified **./application/config/foreign_chars.php**

```
$foreign_characters = array(
    '/ä|æ|ǽ/' => 'ae',
    '/ö|œ/' => 'oe',
    '/ü/' => 'ue',
    '/Ä/' => 'Ae',
    '/Ü/' => 'Ue',
    '/Ö/' => 'Oe',
    '/À|Á|Â|Ã|Ä|Å|Ǻ|Ā|Ă|Ą|Ǎ/' => 'A',
    '/à|á|â|ã|å|ǻ|ā|ă|ą|ǎ|ª/' => 'a',
    '/Ç|Ć|Ĉ|Ċ|Č/' => 'C',
    '/ç|ć|ĉ|ċ|č/' => 'c',
    '/Ð|Ď|Đ/' => 'D',
    '/ð|ď|đ/' => 'd',
    '/È|É|Ê|Ë|Ē|Ĕ|Ė|Ę|Ě/' => 'E',
    '/è|é|ê|ë|ē|ĕ|ė|ę|ě/' => 'e',
    '/Ĝ|Ğ|Ġ|Ģ/' => 'G',
    '/ĝ|ğ|ġ|ģ/' => 'g',
    '/Ĥ|Ħ/' => 'H',
    '/ĥ|ħ/' => 'h',
    '/Ì|Í|Î|Ï|Ĩ|Ī|Ĭ|Ǐ|Į|İ/' => 'I',
    '/ì|í|î|ï|ĩ|ī|ĭ|ǐ|į|ı/' => 'i',
    '/Ĵ/' => 'J',
    '/ĵ/' => 'j',
    '/Ķ/' => 'K',
    '/ķ/' => 'k',
    '/Ĺ|Ļ|Ľ|Ŀ|Ł/' => 'L',
    '/ĺ|ļ|ľ|ŀ|ł/' => 'l',
    '/Ñ|Ń|Ņ|Ň/' => 'N',
    '/ñ|ń|ņ|ň|ŉ/' => 'n',
    '/Ò|Ó|Ô|Õ|Ō|Ŏ|Ǒ|Ő|Ơ|Ø|Ǿ/' => 'O',
    '/ò|ó|ô|õ|ō|ŏ|ǒ|ő|ơ|ø|ǿ|º/' => 'o',
    '/Ŕ|Ŗ|Ř/' => 'R',
    '/ŕ|ŗ|ř/' => 'r',
    '/Ś|Ŝ|Ş|Š/' => 'S',
    '/ś|ŝ|ş|š|ſ/' => 's',
    '/Ţ|Ť|Ŧ/' => 'T',
    '/ţ|ť|ŧ/' => 't',
    '/Ù|Ú|Û|Ũ|Ū|Ŭ|Ů|Ű|Ų|Ư|Ǔ|Ǖ|Ǘ|Ǚ|Ǜ/' => 'U',
    '/ù|ú|û|ũ|ū|ŭ|ů|ű|ų|ư|ǔ|ǖ|ǘ|ǚ|ǜ/' => 'u',
    '/Ý|Ÿ|Ŷ/' => 'Y',
    '/ý|ÿ|ŷ/' => 'y',
    '/Ŵ/' => 'W',
    '/ŵ/' => 'w',
    '/Ź|Ż|Ž/' => 'Z',
    '/ź|ż|ž/' => 'z',
    '/Æ|Ǽ/' => 'AE',
    '/ß/'=> 'ss',
    '/Ĳ/' => 'IJ',
    '/ĳ/' => 'ij',
    '/Œ/' => 'OE',
    '/š/' => 's',
    '/đ/' => 'd',
    '/č/' => 'c',
    '/ć/' => 'c',
    '/ž/' => 'z',
    '/Š/' => 'S',
    '/Đ/' => 'D',
    '/Č/' => 'C',
    '/Ć/' => 'C',
    '/Ž/' => 'Z',
    '/ƒ/' => 'f'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed $product_name_safe = FALSE; on system/libraries/Cart.php and fixed

Comment: You should avoid changing anything in the system folder, you can extend the functionality using a custom class in the `application/libraries/` folder