# CodeIgniter - Does 'name' regex match in Cart class support Unicode?

Tags: regex, codeigniter

I want to include unicode characters (to be more specific, Tamil words) in the 'name' of my Code Igniter cart.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801750/why-codeigniter-shopping-cart-class-doesnt-allow-any-special-character-in-the-na) example.  I tried the following, so that the regex could match anything:

```
$this->cart->product_name_rules = '.+';
$this->cart->product_name_rules = '.*';
$this->cart->product_name_rules = '.';
```

But for all these, I get the error "An invalid name was submitted as the product name: சும்மாவா சொன்னாங்க பெரியவங்க The name can only contain alpha-numeric characters, dashes, underscores, colons, and spaces" in my log.

Also, thinking it could be due to unicode support, I tried the following:

```
$this->cart->product_name_rules = '\p{Tamil}';
```

But to no avail.  Can you please point if something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding each Tamil character individually to your regex. I had to do this for special characters in input keys:

```
    if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9àÀâÂäÄáÁãÃéÉèÈêÊëËìÌîÎïÏòÒôÔöÖõÕùÙûÛüÜçÇ’ñÑß¡¿œŒæÆåÅøØÃ¶:_\.\-\/-\\\,]+$/i", $str))
    {
        exit('Disallowed Key Characters.');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  Trying this out and a similar solution.  Currently facing a tangential problem, but let you know the outcome of this once again.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, it works.  On a sidenote, I tried doing this instead of typing all tamil chars:
    "\x{0B80}-\x{0BFF}"
That works too.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jefim.eu/blog/2009/12/codeigniter-cart-crap-with-cyrillic-characters/) he posted how did he managed to save the cyrilic character in Codeigniter 1.7.2's cart.